# Good practice for types in C which are not needed in certain configurations

Tags: c, types, c-preprocessor

I am writing an abstraction layer for thread-related functions in a C project. Not all platforms for which the code can be built support multithreading; alternatives are available for these platforms.

The header file defines a preprocessor macro if multithreading is supported, so preprocessor conditionals can be used to enable and disable blocks of code which are only required with multithreading (or only without).

Functions are thin wrappers around their native implementations, which can differ from platform to platform. Types are mapped to the corresponding native types with

```
#define mythread pthread_t
```

and similar.

In order to avoid having to clutter code with conditionals every time a lock needs to be acquired or released, most functions can be called even in single-threaded builds, which makes them no-ops. Conditionals are therefore needed only when spawning or joining threads, or for the substitutes thereof. (Attempting to call the thread creation function on a single-threaded build will generate a compiler error.)

This also means the abstracted thread types need to map to something even when threads are not supported, as there may be local variables of these types (again, to avoid cluttering the code with conditionals). So far I am mapping them to `void` on single-threaded builds like this:

```
#ifdef HAVE_POSIX_THREADS
#define mythread pthread_t
#else
#ifdef HAVE_FUNKY_THREADS
#define mythread FThread
#else /* no supported native thread API available, single-threaded build */
#define mythread void
#endif
```

This, however, comes at the expense of not being able to use declarations like:

```
mythread new_thread;
```

(which would declare a `void` variable, invalid in C). That could be worked around by working only with pointers to these types—in fact, every function that initializes any of these types allocates the memory and returns a pointer to it.

**The question**: I was wondering if there is a more elegant way for situations like these.

Comment: And the question is....? (hidden at the very end)... - personal observation: the question would be more understandable if it was placed at the beginning of the explanation or in a separate sentence.

Comment: Can you add some code to show exactly what your "inelegant way" looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is okay to just do

```
#else
#define mythread int
#endif
```

And you can probably make all your thin wrapper functions `static inline xxx xxx(xxx)`, though this is not really necessary because almost every modern compilers just treat `inline` as a hint. After doing these, almost every modern compiler will inline your wrapper functions and figure out that `new_thread` in your `mythread new_thread` is actually unused then optimize it out.

Note: **(Just personal comment, probably off-topic)** Do not use macro conditionals unless necessary. Compiler optimizations like dead code and unused variable elimination is your good friend. Though not in your case, in the GNU coding guideline it is encouraged to use

```
if(some_compiler_flag){ //some_compiler_flag is an 0/1 flag
xxx;
}
```

instead of

```
#ifdef some_compiler_flag
xxx
#endif
```

Modern compilers will compile to the same result, and the previous one is more readable and more friendly to static analysis tools and auto-completion, which make your life easier.

In your case, if it is possible to restructure your code I'll prefer to use all those thread types as **opaque pointers**. For example,

```
//In public headers
union ptr_my_thread_;
typedef ptr_my_thread union ptr_my_thread_;
int my_thread_init(ptr_my_thread);
...
```

And then deal with platform-specific code in your implementation files

```
//In config.h, which takes care of platform dependent flags
#define HAVE_POSIX_THREADS 1
#define HAVE_FUNKY_THREADS 0
...

//In your implementation file
#include <config.h>
union ptr_my_thread_{
    pthread_t *posix;
    FThread *funky;
}
int my_thread_init(ptr_my_thread new_thread){
    if(HAVE_POSIX_THREADS){
        xxx;
    }
}
```

This will enforce modularity and separation of platform dependent code.

Comment: *Do not use macro conditionals ...*  Writing code that supports both Windows and POSIX systems like that would require jumping through all kinds of hoops and/or conditional compilation of different source files.  Good luck trying to compile C code on Linux that has `WaitForSingleObject()` in some sort of contrived `if(some_compiler_flag){ ... }` construct.  How the heck would that even link on Linux?

Comment: Meanwhile, I think this is a quite common accepted stylish suggestion, not barely personal opinion, because it is written into the GNU code guideline...

Comment: Believe or not, it WILL compile and link normally (even when using O0 flag with clang), just try it yourself. I experimented using clang 7, but any gcc/clang in 10 years should work. Indeed, almost every modern compiler will eliminate the code in if(0){...} block, and those non-exist function calls not even go into the compiled object file. Anyway, as I said, do not use macro conditionals **unless necessary**. There are occasions that they are necessary. Just do not use it everywhere when there are better solutions because it will mess up type check, static analysis and auto completion.

Comment: Show me in the C standard where code in an `if ( condition ) { ... }` block is eliminated just because `condition` is `0` at compile time.  Are you **really** proposing relying on such unspecified behavior for what is obviously cross-platform code?  Have you **ever** had to develop and maintain multithreaded cross-platform code that has to run on Linux, Solaris, Windows, AIX, and MVS/OS?  I'm guessing the answer to that is, "No".  Just because GCC does something doesn't make it universal.  Does GCC even work in non-POSIX environments?

Comment: This depends on your scenario. For me, I mainly code for Windows, Linux and macOS and use gcc or clang as compiler, and it is fine staying with the guideline. If you know ypu are going to build on some platform without gcc, of course you should not rely on such behaviour, however you should still encapsulate code with compile branches and keep minimal use of macro conditionals because it greatly reduces maintainability.